# C++ Array of pointers: how delete

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-arrays, delete-operator

Consider the following code:

```
class Search
{
    List** openList;
    int tam;

    Search(int t)
    {
        tam = t;
        openList = new List*[tam];
        for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++)
        {
            openList [i] = new List();
        }
    }

    virtual ~Search();
}
```

How should be the correct destructor?

Now, I have this:

```
Search::~Search() 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < tam; i++) 
    {
        delete openList[i]
    }
    delete[] openList;
}
```

But, this code breaks my program when I execute this recurrently (sometimes in init and sometimes in destructor) so... it's incorrect.

Any idea?

Thanks you so much :)!

Comment: The code you show looks OK to me. The problem must be in the code you haven't shown. Though you could save yourself a lot of trouble if you make your `openList` a `std::vector<List>` and forget about explicit heap allocation.

Answer (score 0):

You are violating the [rule of three](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), which is a hallmark of preventing yourself from broken code.

It says that because you have a user defined destructor, you almost certainly need a user defined copy constructor, and a user defined `operator=()` overload. Let's implement the simplest version of that for your code, which is to ban those transformations:

```
class Search {
  public:
    Search(int t) {
      tam = t;
      openList = new List*[tam];
      for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++)
      {
        openList [i] = new List();
      }
    }

    virtual ~Search() {
      for(int i = 0; i < tam; i++) 
        delete openList[i]
          delete[] openList;
    }

    Search & operator=(Search const &) = delete;
    Search(Search const &) = delete;

  private:
    List** openList;
    int tam;
}
```